# Include smarty in php's __autoload gives Class 'Smarty_Internal_Template' not found

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I have a autoload function like this:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    //define('DOCROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

    $filename = "../sys/class/class." . strtolower($class) . ".inc.php";
    //$filename = DOCROOT . "/sys/class/class." . strtolower($class) . ".inc.php";

    if ( file_exists($filename) )
    {
            include_once $filename;
    }

}
```

I renamed the smarty file to `class.smarty.inc.php` so it's included in the autoload, but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Smarty_Internal_Template' not found in /var/www/v3/sys/class/class.smarty.inc.php on line 441
```

Don't know what that mean..

Comment: You should always use `spl_autoload_register()`, because if some other library registers an autoloader there, `__autoload()` will not get called anymore (`spl_autoload_register('__autoload');`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** modify 3rd-party-libraries. Just create a second autoloader that follows Smarty's naming convention.

```
function defaultAutoloader($className) {
    // your code ($file = /path/to/my/lib/{{ CLASS }}.inc.php)

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function smartyAutoloader($className) {
    // code ($file = /path/to/smarty/{{ CLASS }}.php)

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

spl_autoload_register('defaultAutoloader');
spl_autoload_register('smartyAutoloader');
```

Comment: Can't say I agree with your first statement, nothing wrong with modification 3rd party libraries in my book, but it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way your autoloader maps the classname to a filename leads to the filename `class.smarty_internal_template.inc.php`, which is obviously not the filename you expect. I dont know how Smarty is structured, but you should make sure the autoloader can find any of its classes.